# how to connect to psql on google VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, psql

I can connect and ssh into the external VM. But I have a hard time accessing the postgres serve on the VM. I have done the following

1. I updated the postgresql.conf to

   ```
   listen_addresses = '*'
   ```

   `port = 5432`

   2. I have did the following to my firewall.

[image]

what should i do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall rule is really insecure (you are allowing everyone on internet to connect to your GCE instance using all the ports) and maybe another firewall rule is blocking this rule due to the priority is really low (the greater the priority number is, the lower priority has). Did you follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) tutorial? once you add `listen_addresses = '*'`, you need to restart your PostgreSQL service with `sudo service postgresql restart`.

Also, you need to create 2 firewall rules, one for ingress and another one for egress. Both to accept traffic to `tcp:5432`, can you please create 2 firewall rules with more priority that accepts traffic from that port with a smaller IP range?

Comment: Thanks this helped. The only question I have is with the range of the IP access. we use different VMS (that might come and go into existence) as our IP address. How can I allow for them to have access if the ips are changing and I dont have listen_addresses = '*'?

Comment: @user1871528 those VMs are local VMs or GCE instances? if are GCE instances, you can reserve static IPs for free to use them in your GCE instances. If not... It's much complicated and costly. However, you can use 0.0.0.0/0 as you had, but it's a bit risky.

Comment: Some are some are not GCP. For the GCP, when I create a vm can i give it a higher and lower range?

Comment: @user1871528 the IP is set randomly in your GCP instance, but you can set that IP to be static and will not change. Also, in your FW rule you can add all the IPs of your GCP instances one by one.